# Can I snapshot an OS X Application installation?

Tags: macos, applications, package-management

I would like to:

- take a snapshot of my OS X system
- install an application
- and take a new snapshot.

Comparing both snapshots (file hash) would show me what settings(plist files) and files were created/edited during the installation.

It is very popular on Windows (VMware ThinApp, RegShot, Symantec Endpoint Virtualization Suite... etc.).

Is there an OS X tool or software to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

[File Buddy for OS X](http://www.skytag.com/filebuddy/en/) has a snapshot feature: Just create a snapshot before and after the installation and first launch of the app. Then open them in compare mode and you will get three text files of added, modified and deleted items.